# C++ templates versus C# generic method with various parameters

Tags: c#, generics

in C++, this works.

```
template<class T> void func(T t)
{ t.method(); }
```

How to implement this in C#?  Here is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
void func<T>(T t)
{ t.method(); }
```

Or it is impossible to do this in C#?

Answer (score 3):

The following should work

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static void MyMethod<T>(T t) where T : class
  {
     t.ToString(); // Note: for this to work we need to KNOW the type which defines `method`.
  }
}
```

as well as this:

```
public class MyBase
{
   void Method();
}

public static class MyClassForBase
{
  public static void MyMethod<T>(T t) where T : MyBase
  {
     t.Method(); // Note: anything from MyBase is now available
  }
}
```

Last, but not least, you can use late-binding like so

```
public static class MyClassDynamic
{
  public static void MyMethod(dynamic t)
  {
     t.Method(); // Note: if t doesn't have a `Method` defined, the code will crush-n-burn at runtime
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a method that takes a generic parameter, you can only call methods on that parameter that the compiler knows will be there.

In your example:

```
void func<T>(T t)
{
    t.method();
}
```

the compiler does not know that the method `method` exists, so this will not work.

You can tell the compiler which methods will be available by using [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). For example, if the method is defined on an interface then you can constrain it correctly using a `where` clause like this:

```
pubic interface IClassWithMethod
{
    void method();
}

void func<T>(T t) where T : IClassWithMethod
{
    t.method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics in C# are NOT the same as templates in C++. C++ templates are essentially marcos that are applied to code at compile-time depending on what types they are used with. So if you tried to use your template on a class that did not have a `.method()` method, it would fail at compile time.

C# generics instead require that whatever type `T` *could* be must define any methods and properties that the generic method uses. So if you have a base type or interface that defines a `.method()` method, you would constrain your generic method to that type:

```
void func<T>(T t) where T:IHaveMethod
{ t.method(); }
```

So long as the `IHaveMethod` interface defines `method()`, the generic function will compile. Note that in your specific example the generic method is useless since you can just call `method` on the interface type.

Where generics is more useful is when you want the return type to be based on the input type:

```
T func<T>(T t) where T:IHaveMethod
{ t.method(); return t;}
```

Now, not only does `method` gets called, but the return type is exactly the type of the generic argument, not just an `IHaveMethod`, which might limit what you can do with the return without casting.

Bottom line, don't think of generics the same way you think of C++ templates. THere are very fundamental differences that will make it harder for you to see when and where generics can/should be used.